# Registry class. If key exist

Tags: c#, if-statement, testing, registry, regedit

Im using the **Microsoft.Win32.Registry** class. Im trying to make a if RegKey exist statement but don't know how

I want something like this:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\test");
if(key.keyExist("yourKey")) Console.WriteLine("yourKey exist!");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, the SubKey is stored in a path in the system.

So you can do something like this to check out if the SubKey exists:

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\test"))
{
       if (key != null)
       {
            Console.WriteLine("yourKey exist!");
       }
       else
       {
           // e.g. create SubKey
       }
}
```