# Registry class. If value exist

Tags: c#, class, if-statement, registry, regedit

Im using the Microsoft.Win32.Registry class. Im trying to make a if value exist statement but don't know how

I want something like this:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpXmb.png)

```
private RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Test");
if(key.ValueExist("myValue")) Console.WriteLine("value exist!");
```

Comment: `CreateSubKey` just defines the name. Use `SetValue()` to specify [the type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registryvaluekind). Unless you just want read a Value, not create it, that is.

Comment: Didn't my answer [Registry class. If value exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61259936/12417300) to your question help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood you properly.

For example you can do something like this

```
public static bool checkMachineType()
{    
    RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"System\Set\services\something", true);
    return (key.GetValueNames().Contains("value"));
}
```

For Registry Value you can get names of Values for the current key and check if this array contains the needed Value name.

In your code this should be like this

```
private RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Test");

RegistryKey getKey= Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Test", true);
if(getKey.GetValueNames().Contains("value")) 
{
  Console.WriteLine("value exist!");
}
```